# Simple Logical Simplification - Distributive Law

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I can't seem to understand the hopefully simple step of getting from :

$(a \land b \land c) \lor (a \land b \land \lnot c)$

to:

$(a \land b) \land (c \lor \lnot c)$

This step is in the answers and only has '(distribution)' written next to it, however even when breaking this down into several parts with Distributive Laws, I got nothing close to the expected solution (most likely my fault rather than teacher's). So any help explaining this step would very much be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apply the distributive law to $d \wedge (c\vee \neg c)$ where $d=a\wedge b$. Then you get $$\begin{array}{rcl}d\wedge (c\vee \neg c)&=&(d\wedge c )\vee (d\wedge \neg c)\\&=&((a\wedge b)\wedge c)\vee ((a \wedge b)\wedge \neg c)\\&=&(a\wedge b\wedge c)\vee (a\wedge b \wedge \neg c). \end{array}$$Hope this helps!

Comment: Ah, to your specific question you just have to reverse the steps I did above, but this doesn't change anything to the argument.

Answer (score 0):

The equivalence is indeed an instance of Distribution ... it just doesn't *feel* like Distribution.

To be specific, going from:

$(a \land b) \land (c \lor \lnot c)$

to:

$(a \land b \land c) \lor (a \land b \land \lnot c)$

feels like a 'proper' Distribution. However, going the other way around, i.e. going from:

$(a \land b \land c) \lor (a \land b \land \lnot c)$

to:

$(a \land b) \land (c \lor \lnot c)$

feels like something that should be called 'Reverse Distribution' or 'Factoring' or 'Collecting Common Terms' ....but not 'Distribution'.

And yet, since Distribution is an *equivalence*, you can go both ways, and so it really is Distribution.

I see this as a clear example of how language can have an enormous power over our thinking. Or, more to the point: how maybe we should try and come up with a better name than 'Distribution'.

Answer (score -1):

It might help to put it into words:

I will use $TRUE/FALSE$ notation.

$A,B,C$ are $TRUE$ or $A,B$, NOT $C$ are $TRUE$. In either case $A$ and $B$ are $TRUE$.

Then either $C$ is $TRUE$ or NOT $C$ is $TRUE$ since this is an or statement and may be either one.